# Getting the bytes[] / stream of an Image or ImageSource in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I've been digging into Xamarin.Forms.Labs to learn more about how Images are accessed and manipulated. Saving an image to an Android/iOS photo gallery works fine, as does retrieving an image from either, at least with user interaction.

The problem is that I'd like to be able to save some files internally to the program. Actually saving a file itself doesn't seem to be a problem - I've written up an interface/DependencyService solution for that.

What I can't seem to do is access the bytes[] or stream of the image data itself with a Xamarin.Forms Image or ImageSource. Reading a stream into the ImageSource is relatively straightforward with the static method, so how do I get these bytes out in order to save the file within the program itself?

To frame this: I'm working on an app right now where the user takes/selects pictures to include within a form, and the form is eventually posted to a website. So being able to actually save the pictures, or access the data itself in order to transfer it, is pretty key.

Comment: Digging around in Forms.Labs, I found that MediaPicker apparently does what I need by exposing access to the Stream of whatever media it takes from the Camera or the file library. That still leaves me wondering how to get at the stream for an image itself - in particular here I'm thinking of the SignaturePad images - but at least that's progress, and there may be a solution built into that as well.

Answer (score 0):

One really hacky way to do that would be to write a custom renderer for your image. Then the renderer will get the `byte[]/Stream` from the native control. Here's a very rough implementation without any error handling to help you get started:

```
public class MyImage : Image
{
    public Func<byte[]> GetBytes { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the **iOS** renderer:

```
public class MyImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var newImage = e.NewElement as MyImage;
        if (newImage != null)
        {
            newImage.GetBytes = () =>
            {
                return this.Control.Image.AsPNG().ToArray();
            };
        }

        var oldImage = e.OldElement as MyImage;
        if (oldImage != null)
        {
            oldImage.GetBytes = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The **Android** one is a little more involved:

```
public class MyImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var newImage = e.NewElement as MyImage;
        if (newImage != null)
        {
            newImage.GetBytes = () =>
            {
                var drawable = this.Control.Drawable;
                var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(drawable.IntrinsicWidth, drawable.IntrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
                drawable.Draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, ms);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            };
        }

        var oldImage = e.OldElement as MyImage;
        if (oldImage != null)
        {
            oldImage.GetBytes = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the usage is the kind of obvious:

```
var bytes = myImage.GetBytes?.Invoke();
```

Extending the idea to support streams should be pretty straightforward. The obvious caveat is that the forms control (`MyImage`) retains a reference to its renderer via `GetBytes()`, but that seems to be unavoidable.

Comment: GetBytes is null for me in the renderer :/ #Android

Comment: Did you register the renderer? `GetBytes` is a function you assign in `OnElementChanged`, so it should not be null.